# What is the scope for a function's arguments when dealing with inner asynchronous calls?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, q

In my following example the arguments of one of the express app callbacks are behaving differently depending on if they are encapsulated inside an auxiliary function or not. I have solved my problem but I would like to understand better what is happening here.

`getItem` and `buildView` return promises created with `Q`.
The following code works (i. e. no fail callback is ever called):

```
var app = require("express")();
app.get('/item/:itemId', function(req, res){
    var showItem= function(item){
        var s = function(x){res.send(x);};
        buildView(item).then(s).fail(console.log);
    };

    var showError = function(error){
        res.send(error.message);
    };

    getItem(req.params.exception_id)
        .then(showItem).fail(showError);
});
```

And the following code doesn't (console.log prints `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined]`):

```
var app = require("express")();
app.get('/item/:itemId', function(req, res){
    var showItem= function(item){
        buildView(item).then(res.send).fail(console.log);
    };

    var showError = function(error){
        res.send(error.message);
    };

    getItem(req.params.exception_id)
        .then(showItem).fail(showError);
});
```

(The difference is in the fourth and fifth lines, the fourth is deleted and the fifth is modified).

It is clear that the promise `buildView` is being resolved successfully, otherwise the first approach would fail as well; and until the point where `buildView` is applied both implementations have followed exactly  the same steps.

Why are not these implementations getting exactly the same? 
Shouldn't it be that when the promise `buildView` is resolved `.then(res.send)` should execute `res.send` with the resolved value of the promise as its argument? (i. e. the first implementation).

Comment: Can you try `buildView(item).then(res.send.bind(this)).fail(console.log);` or `buildView(item).then(res.send.bind(res)).fail(console.log);` ?

Comment: ```buildView(item).then(res.send.bind(res))``` binds the right context for the function. Forgot that in javascript ```this``` is a bit too special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work:

```
buildView(item).then(res.send.bind(res)).fail(console.log);
```

When you simply do `then(res.send)`, `this` context of `res` is lost: `send` function is detached from `res` object context.

It has nothing to do with asynchronicity as this is a [known *feature* of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in JavaScript.

Comment: The second one should work. The first is definitely wrong. But it would be better if you can explain WHY.